# I have a model Job with a manytomany field benefit. How will I make it accept pk value and str value?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How will I make the many-to-many field benefit in the job model which has a field name accept string also? If the new value is given it has to create a new instance also.

now I'm getting the error  "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."

```
{
  
    "benefit": [
        1
    ],
   
}
```

what I have to input is

```
{
      
        "benefit": [
            1,"new_instance"
        ],
       
    }
```

and create new instance as the name in the benefits model.

Comment: Can you provide some code

Comment: please check now